# Create React App Typecsript issues (keyword interface is reserved)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, typescript-typings, lerna

It is a Lerna project. When I try to build the main package it throws the following exceptions:

```
    Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (3:0)
    > interface MyInterface {

    ...

    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
    > export declare enum MyEnum {
```

These files are in one of the submodules.

Typescript and react-scripts versions:

```
"react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
"typescript": "^3.8.3"
```

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for it?